# Docker volume "./lib:/lib" causes "no such file or directory

Tags: spring, docker, docker-compose

I have this simple Dockerfile for Spring:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine

VOLUME /tmp

ARG JAR_FILE=target/chatbot-2.4.3.jar

COPY ${JAR_FILE} /opt/sprintbotserver/chatbot.jar
COPY . /opt/sprintbotserver

ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","./opt/sprintbotserver/chatbot.jar"]
```

and I'm deploying it via `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3"
services:
  sprintbotserver:
    container_name: sprintbotserver
    image: sprintbotserver:latest
    volumes:
      - "./logs:/logs"
      - "./chatbots:/chatbots"
      - "./config:/config"
      - "./db:/db"
      - "./demo:/demo"
      - "./dic:/dic"
      - "./lib:/lib"    //this line causes error
      - "./models:/models"
      - "./service:/service"
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
```

I've commented on the troubling line. All volumes except this one work as intended. When I add this line, I get `standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "no such file or directory"`.

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

`/lib` is a standard directory in Linux, containing important parts of the system; mounting anything else over it will probably make pretty much everything break.

Can you (a) use a different directory name, or (b) run the whole thing in a subdirectory (eg `/opt`, so you then use `./lib:/opt/lib`)?

Comment: How do i do that? I've already stated the "/opt/sprintbotserver" path in my Dockerfile. How to change it in `docker-compose`?

Comment: Can you please help me here? My container only sees the files when I place them like that, and I don't know how to change it... I mean change the mounting path of my `docker-compose`

Comment: Make the targets of the bind mounts be _e.g._ `/opt/sprintbotserver/lib`, not `/lib` in the container filesystem's root.  Restructuring the setup so you only need one bind mount, or zero, would simplify this substantially.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, the keyword I was missing is WORKDIR :)